# Проблема со скроллом на телефоне

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть сайт https://www.eko-rb.ru. Если допустим cо смартофона зайти во вкладку Специалисты клиники через вкладку меню "Специалисты", то надо несколько раз свайпнуть чтобы сайт начался скроллит.То есть при первой попытке скролла, сайт обратно возвращается к хедеру, на одной странице уже решил этому проблему вставив
body{
overflow:hidden;

}
Но проблема на всем сайте, и на других страницах не работает
Если кто не понял, зайдите сюда https://www.eko-rb.ru/about/ с смартфона и попробуйте спуститься вниз

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Ну у меня все в поряде потому что быстрый инет щас на телефоне, значит проблема в следущем какой-то из скриптов долго подгружаеться и не дает другим загрузиться.